# Invoke jqplot multiple graphs in one container page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jqplot

I´m do several graphic template for each type that i could use after.

All the graphs are jsp and share the characteristic that use json for the data. some graphs are updated dynamically with a timer.

My idea was to make a jsp container that i can invoke the graphs to use, but dont work well and found two problems.

The function that is used to invoke is this:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result1').load('Bars1.jsp'); 
    //$('#result2').load('Bars2.jsp');
    $('#result3').load('./../Area/Area1.jsp')    
});
 </script>
```

My first problem is that the graph only works when the path of the container is the same as any of the graphics I invoke. Also works when I invoke a graph that is in another different route. But when refresh sometimes one or two graphs not appear.

But if the path to the container dont have other jsp graphic doesn't work. example

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result1').load('/Bars/Bars1.jsp');
    $('#result2').load('/Area/Area1.jsp');   
});
 </script>
```

i´ve done everithing, use the libraries in the container, use libraries in each graph with the path to the container and dont work.

Help please. Regards.